# Why would you need to put a domain name when install a Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

When you install an Oracle database or instance, you are able to assign a domain name.

An Example:

```
SID: orcl

Domain: world.com

Service: orcl.world.com
```

Why would it be necessary to add or configure a domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows you to have more than one DB with the same name in the same network. If you have only one it can be the network domain.